# Delayed Job not scheduling on time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, delayed-job

I have the following delayed job setup in my model as follows:

```
def expire_listing(listing_id)
    puts "EXPIRING"
end
handle_asynchronously :expire_listing, :run_at => Proc.new { 1.minutes.from_now }
```

However when the delayed job gets scheduled as follows:

```
 #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 5, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: 
"--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject...", last_error: nil, 
run_at: "2014-10-23 18:13:00", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, 
queue: nil, created_at: "2014-10-23 18:12:00", 
updated_at: "2014-10-23 18:12:00">
```

You can notice the **run_at** time is 4 hours ahead (**2014-10-23 18:13:00**) of the current time which is **2014-10-23 14:12:00**

How can i fix this so that it actually runs 1 minute from the current time?

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot to run the jobs. Simply run the following and it should work (Rails 4).

```
bin/delayed_job start
```

Answer (score -1):

try using this gem, it's really useful https://github.com/KensoDev/perform_later